# Don't show tech-focused blog posts on non-tech sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, blog, community-bulletin

The Stack Overflow Blog has a number of articles about technology, such as [Mapping Ecosystems of Software Development](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/10/03/mapping-ecosystems-software-development/?cb=1). However, they appear on all Stack Exchange sites in the sidebar, including ones that have no relation to technology such as [Movies & TV Stack Exchange](https://movies.stackexchange.com).

[image]

I don't see the benefit of showing tech-only blog posts on non-tech websites, since they have no connection to the subject matter.

Would it be possible to only show these sorts of blog posts on tech sites (e.g. Stack Overflow, Superuser, Software Engineering, Code Review) and not non-tech sites (e.g. Movies, Parenting, Islam, Coffee)?

(Of course, any blog posts that would be of interests to all sites, like a new feature available across all of Stack Exchange, would still be welcome).

Comment: I talked to [Kaitlin Pike](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/315919/kcpike) earlier today about this and we're going to set up a new category tag on the blog that will only be sync'd to the community bulletin on technology sites.

Comment: @AdamLear Wonderful news! Looking forward to that change. Glad that it seems to be a simple fix.

Comment: that's a good way for people, who are not aware of tech, to learn tech.

Comment: and there is no movie blog in SE at all. that sidebar is universal. it show blog post, feature on meta posts from MSE and the site's child meta and hot meta posts (if there is any)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry this took a while, but I pushed a change live where posts with the "bulletin" category on them (naming is hard!) will only be sync'd to the bulletins on sites that fall into the [Technology category](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-oldest).

Post authors and the blog team still have control over whether or not that category is specified, but at least we have a way to more finely control the audience here. Going forward, you should see fewer, if any, posts on how things are going in the tech world out there in the CB.

Comment: Maybe also do the same with blog posts having the [stackoverflow tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/tags/stackoverflow/)?