# Why are the developer survey results getting shown on non-computer SE sites?

Tags: bug, blog, sidebar

[image]

I'm pretty sure the good people of [The Great Outdoors](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/) (a Se site about hiking, climbing, etc.) have literally no interest in a survey of computer programmers. So why is this being shown in the side nav?

As per [comment below](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307906/why-are-the-developer-survey-results-getting-shown-on-non-computer-se-sites#comment1002030_307906) **can this be changed to have the correct tags please?**

Comment: Because the blog author forgot to add the [bulletin tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/tags/bulletin/) to it, which would cause it [to not appear in the sidebar for non-tech sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301676/dont-show-tech-focused-blog-posts-on-non-tech-sites).

Comment: *cough* answers in Comments? Really? ;p