# Stop misusing the blog sidebar and restrict it to posts which are actually announcements of network-wide significance

Tags: discussion, status-completed, blog, sidebar, community-bulletin

[Catija has recently explained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343846/256282) that which blog posts get displayed in the side bar for each site depends on a blog tag:

> It's tag-dependent.
>
> - Blog posts tagged "bulletin" appear in the sidebar on sites that are considered technology sites (based on the sites listed in the footer) but not on others.
> - Blog posts tagged "announcements" appear everywhere on the network.
> - There's a third for "stack-overflow" which only appears on SO unless it also has one of the other two tags.
> - We also have an "international" tag for blog posts written in other languages and that can be paired with a language tag to cause the post to appear on the Russian, Spanish, Portuguese or Japanese SO sites

However sometimes other posts also get shown in the blog sidebar without any of those tags...

The [announcements tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/tags/announcements/) is not however limited to actual announcements of relevance to non-technology focused sites. It also has included:

- announcements of Stack Overflow only features: [1](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/30/introducing-dark-mode-for-stack-overflow/), [2](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/04/01/ultra-dark-mode-april-fools/), [3](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/05/06/introducing-collections-on-stack-overflow-for-teams/)
- ads for Teams: [1](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/03/critical-tools-united-for-a-better-developer-workflow/), [2: "Coming together as a community to connect"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/19/coming-together-as-a-community-to-connect/) (this one's particular gross because it looks from the title like it will be something heartfelt, but it's just a regular ad, trying to take advantage of the pandemic)
- profiles on [bootcamps](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/01/02/this-veteran-started-a-code-bootcamp-for-people-who-went-to-bootcamp/), [other education organisations](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/01/08/tapping-into-the-coding-power-of-migrants-and-refugees-in-mexico/), and [programming languages](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/01/29/the-live-coding-language-that-lets-you-be-an-actual-rock-star/), [VPNs](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/13/scaling-your-vpn-overnight/)
- podcast episodes: [1](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/31/podcast-222-learning-from-our-moderators/)
- [weird fiction](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/12/23/a-holiday-carol-for-coders/)
- Two sets of post roundups, and not just [the announcement of the The Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/10/01/introducing-overflow-newsletter-cassidy-williams/), which was a legitimate use of the Announcements tag, but the actual roundup posts:

  - The Overflow:
    [1](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/10/03/the-overflow-for-october-4-2019/),
    [2](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/01/24/the-overflow-9-rust-and-redux/),
    [3](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/02/07/the-overflow-10-the-500-mile-email/), [4](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/06/the-overflow-12-plain-text/),
    [5](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/04/10/the-overflow-16-how-many-jobs-can-be-done-at-home/),
    [6](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/05/01/the-overflow-19-jokes-on-us/),
    [7](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/05/08/the-overflow-20-sharpen-your-skills/);
  - and StackOverflowKnows:
    [1](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/01/17/this-week-stackoverflowknows-syntactic-sugar-overfit-or-nah-and-the-definition-of-norm/),
    [2](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/01/31/this-week-stackoverflowknows-the-coronavirus-long-tail-sulfuric-acid-spills-and-tiny-malicious-code/),
    [3](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/02/28/this-week-stackoverflowknows-outlaw-wifi-gpu-weakness-and-neutrinos-per-second/?cb=1),
    [4](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/13/this-week-stackoverflowknows-molecule-rings-infected-laptops-and-hmac-limits/)
- SE traffic/data analysis: [1](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/08/08/def-con-stack-overflow-traffic-data-trends/), [2](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/02/28/evaluating-options-amazons-hq2-using-stack-overflow-data/), [3](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/04/20/pandemic-changed-traffic-trends-stack-exchange-sites/), [4](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/04/19/how-often-do-people-actually-copy-and-paste-from-stack-overflow-now-we-know/), [5](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/12/30/how-often-do-people-actually-copy-and-paste-from-stack-overflow-now-we-know/)
- [anti-phishing tips](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/23/defending-yourself-against-coronavirus-scams/)
- posts about working remotely: [1](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/04/13/socializing-with-co-workers-while-social-distancing/)
- posts on the Stack Overflow developer survey: [1](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/08/30/the-full-data-set-for-the-2021-developer-survey-now-available/)
- [pointless fluff from the CEO](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/04/28/agility-starts-with-trust/?cb=1)

It has often been the case that the sidebar will show two blog posts, neither of which should be promoted in this way on non-tech sites (or even arguably on any site).

[image: screenshot of the page sidebar]

I would like to make the simple request that the announcements tag be limited to only those posts which are actually announcements.

Actually, no, I'll go further than that. There needs to be accountability for the way the blog is pushed onto the hundreds of sites in the network. It cannot be the case that one staff member can act like a free agent and push random posts onto our sites without oversight.

Comment: It seems we've been through this already: [Don't show tech-focused blog posts on non-tech sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301676/dont-show-tech-focused-blog-posts-on-non-tech-sites).

Comment: Adblock works just fine on these sort of posts. It baffles me why they're pushing them out network wide.

Comment: The most annoying thing about this for me is that it takes the place of other content. I'd like to see more featured meta posts etc in the side bar, and less generic tech blogging. (To be fair though, there seem to be more SO-specific blog posts lately, which are fairly interesting. The ones that were just "Joe Smith writes about technology Y" were just...weird.)

Comment: @CesarM hi, can you please explain why you added the [tag:status-completed] tag, i.e what exactly was changed? (This question is not even a feature request.) Thanks.

Comment: @ShadowKeepsSocialDistance They've finished their review of it, and since Ryan posted below I haven't seen any objectionably tagged posts.

Comment: @ShadowKeepsSocialDistance the [status] tags are being used as part of our [internal process of responding to meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344586/our-commitment-to-responding-to-meta-and-moderators) and since this was responded to by Ryan with changes to the tags on the blog, it's been responded to accordingly :)

Comment: @CesarM thanks, figured that. The answer was posted long ago, and author has no diamond, so first impression was that there wasn't any official response. :)

Comment: Unless *Dark Mode* makes it so you don't have to sock puppet, I don't see what it has to do with me. It's a post by a free agent, pushing random posts at me, where their job is to do the oversight. *First impressions are* [auto correct].

Comment: The blog post that you linked in your latest edit doesn't seem to have the announcements tag. Either it's been edited out since, or it's a bug that it ended up being featured without the tag.

Comment: The blog post you just edited in now isn't tagged with announcements. It's a **bug** that it's appearing in the bulletin, and not malice on SE's part.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog This has happened so many times that unless you can get confirmation from staff that it was accidental I have to assume it was deliberate. And I think the internal tags/categories the use don't always get shown as visible tags to us. Lots of other syndicated posts didn't have an "announcement" tag.

Comment: I've already asked about this, by the way: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363449/on-all-sites-the-bulletin-incorrectly-displays-certain-blog-posts-for-24-48-hou

Comment: An update: the blog post was removed from the sidebar today. (Intentionally featured blog posts show up for *far* longer.)

Comment: @curiousdannii - on first glance, I can't tell why the one that you added earlier today is showing up.  The tags on it are fairly innocuous.  Unfortunately, I've also got no staff until after the holidays, so this one's going to need to go in the pile to get reviewed when my folks are back.

Comment: "pointless fluff from the CEO" - for a four times a year post from the CEO of the company that runs the network, letting those that *use* the network know how the company is doing.... You may want to reset your expectations as to what's reasonable for the company to share across all sites (and indeed what _may_ be interesting to some of those who use said sites) as it seems more than a little skewed

Comment: @Rob Some of the CEO's posts have been interesting and informative, but this most recent one really was not, IMO.

Answer (score 44):

As a workaround, I am now using this filter with uBlock Origin:

```
stackexchange.com##[href^="https://stackoverflow.blog/"]
```

Honestly your post broke the back of the camel for me. I have been looking at those links for some time now, and I have to say I haven't been interested in a single one.

As others have alluded to, the blog seems to have turned into this weird marketing/advertising thing that I don't want to consume. I am much more interested in the "Featured on Meta" section, as those are usually (or used to be) posted *by users*, or by staff and contain topical information about *what is going on in the community*.

Sadly my filter isn't great, as whoever designed the site put a CSS ID for the entire sidebar, but no ID or unique class on the blog section to allow for easy filtering.

Comment: Here are the filters I use that will remove the blog panel entirely: `*##.s-sidebarwidget--content:has(a[href*="stackoverflow.blog"])` and `*##div.fc-light.s-sidebarwidget--header:has(+ .s-sidebarwidget--content:has(a[href*="stackoverflow.blog"]))`. If other sites match those selectors exactly, you may have to specify stackoverflow, stackexchange and the other few sites with their own domain... but that's unlikely

Comment: @ert It's been changed. it's now s-sidebarwidget--item, not content.

Answer (score 11):

I think the real point ... is simply a re-iteration of what was [written](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341767/285661) in January already: there needs to be a consistent, well thought **strategy** about tags.

Which tags exist, and how exactly are they used, and most importantly: infrastructure around that, to easily use these tags for navigation!

Answer (score 7):

FWIW we recently(-ish) changed the feed of one of the chatrooms in an attempt to filter out the noise.

```
https://stackoverflow.blog/tags/community,company,stackexchange,survey/feed
```

It's *mostly* cleaned up our feed. Unfortunately the most recent Teams ad still ended up getting included, and I don't think it's possible to filter *out* specific tags.

Answer (score 7):

We hear you about the overuse of the announcements tag, so we're going to put into place a formal definition of what gets tagged as an announcement. From here on out, we'll only syndicate company and product announcements and community news that makes sense for network-wide distribution. We'll no longer tag as announcement any blog posts that we may think be of wider interest to our network unless it fits into this definition.

But that means a few of the posts that you highlighted will still show up. While we understand Teams is currently only available for Stack Overflow accounts, we still want the product to be relevant for everyone and to share our progress on it. With that in mind, major announcements of Stack Overflow for Teams features will still be announcements.

Part of the issue here is that we have two things in the blog backend sometimes referred to as tags: categories and tags. A few of the posts mentioned in this list came from experiments to see which one actually triggers syndication. Right now, we're working on a clearer solution that lets us tag a post (with a tag, not a category) that is only to trigger syndication.

tl;dr -- Announcements are only product, company, and community posts from here on out.

Comment: I'm disappointed to see you've stopped following this definition.

Comment: @curiousdannii The blog post that you linked in your latest question edit doesn't seem to have the announcements tag. Either it's been edited out since, or it's a bug that it ended up being featured without the tag.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I think they said before that it was never about the blog tags, but some other system that determined which blog posts were featured.

Comment: I syndicated that one (assuming that you mean the April Fools data post) to everyone because I thought with it being data about the community, it would be of interest to everyone who uses the sites. Apologies if that was in error.

Comment: Sad to see you are again not following the definition you made for yourself.