# The Community Teams @ Stack Exchange and how we work together

Tags: discussion, community, announcements, stack-exchange-team, company

I wanted to share with you about who the people that work on our Community are, and how we are organized. For context, I (Teresa Dietrich) am the head of Product, Community, Design and Engineering, a combined Chief Product and Technology Officer. I joined the company in mid January and report directly to Prashanth Chandrasekar, the CEO. Both of the following teams are members of the organization that I lead.

Our Community Team endeavors to ensure the well-being of our sites and that the needs of our users are heard. That means focusing on things like facilitating communication from our users to the company, and making sure our users are well aware of initiatives coming from inside Stack Overflow. We also are responsible for the trust and safety for our users, and supporting our moderators and curators.

The Community Team is divided into four sub-teams: the Community Engagement and Enablement team, the Trust and Safety Team, the Community Strategy team, and the Community Support team.

- The **Community Engagement and Enablement** team (led by Rosie) is responsible for projects involving tools and requests from the community, such as running elections and handling tickets escalated by moderators.
- The **Trust and Safety** team (led by Cesar) is responsible for handling user safety on the platform, including preventing harassment, PII concerns, and other abusive behaviors on the network.
- The **Community Support** team (also led by Cesar) is responsible for communication and support for moderators and users. This team is who you'll primarily be dealing with when you write us from the /contact pages.
- The **Community Strategy** team  (led by Philippe) consists of the team leads for each of the teams, as well as Slate, who manages special projects for us, and Berthold, who is the main CM for Collectives on Stack Overflow and also previously looked after our liaison work with the product team (this is time spent consulting on tooling, new features, etc., and communicating them out to you, as well as collecting and sharing feedback with the product teams).

You can find out more about who's on the Community Team in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99338/208518).

---

The Community Products organization is responsible for the development of all public-facing products, and is split into a number of teams. Each team has its own area of focus, and is staffed with a Product Manager, Tech Lead, Developers, and Design, along with support from Community Liaisons, Engineering Management, Scrum Leadership, Research, Data, Testing, and Product Marketing.

Here is a breakdown of the team concentrations (there are too many people to list them out here):

- **Community Enablement**: Supporting moderators and community managers through improved tooling and automation
- **Creators & Curators**: Improving the Q&A experience for question askers, answerers, and maintainers
- **Consumers**: Supporting the broader community's experience and their ability to discover content
- **Collectives**: Supporting member and client experiences within Collectives™ on Stack Overflow including Admins and Recognized Members
- **Awareness**: Advertising and sponsorship products across the Stack Overflow ecosystem

I hope this gives you some insights into who we are and how we work together. If you have questions or if there are any clarifications I can make, please put them in an answer and we’ll try to respond as best we can.

Comment: Congratulations to all the folks who were promoted.

Comment: @Philippe You might make a new post. It's weird to see an update on a post starting  "I wanted to share with you about who the people that work on our Community are, and how we are organized. For context, I (Teresa Dietrich) ...". This might be a good opportunity to think about the aging of this kind of posts.

Comment: @Philippe I don't think a new post is necessary and I think it would make things confusing. Also, anyone who has clicked "Follow" on this post, would have to know to click "Follow" on the new post instead, and there is not a single mechanism for notifying all of the followers to do that!

Answer (score 41):

Is the size and composition of the CM Team planned to stay as it is right now for the near future? A significant number of CMs were fired or resigned, but the workload probably didn't get any smaller. A lot of institutional knowledge about community management and the internals of how many SE systems work behind the scenes were also lost at that time.

From my observations, the CMs also aren't exactly good at stepping back and relaxing, I've seen them plenty of times at the weekend or at various odd hours. There's probably a higher chance of burning out as a community manager as the community can't really scale their demands to the workload.

Most recent initiatives to improve community relations seem like good ideas to me. But a lot of them also create more work for the CMs, but the team only got smaller. There are some good parts here like making Yaakov's role as Community Advocate official, that could help with some of the CM workload. If SE doesn't plan to increase the size of the CM Team again, I hope there's at least real progress in automating some of the routine stuff and improving the tools. As otherwise I can't really see how the workload could stay manageable.

Comment: We currently have ongoing discussions about both of these topics.  What is the right way to scale and determine the number of CMs that we have based on community data?  We are working on this so we can know how many we need and will need in the future.  We are also working on identifying actions that can be automated and/or turned into a tool in increase efficiency.  First we need to come up with the answers/solution, then we will work out a path to implement them.

Comment: Its felt like after its peak, its generally been a team that's taken a hit every downsize. The promises of further automation and efficiency are *nice* but we've been hearing them for years as a response to every downsizing or request for additional resources. The recent "realignment" was a kick to the gut too. At some point, its tempting to try to throw more tech at the problem but a large extent of CM work's dealing with people at a human level.We've just heard it often enough that it feels... insufficient and somewhat less meaningful than it needs to be.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I mostly mentioned that part because I consider it more likely that this can be sold to SE management compared to increasing the headcount of the CM team. But yeah, I wouldn't count on this to happen given how often we've talked about that already.

Comment: The big problem with automation isn't that it won't help, @Journeyman - it's that it's expensive. Even more expensive in the short term than hiring more CMs. It is a good long-term investment... But when money is too scarce to hire more staff, it is likely also too scarce to cover enough automation to make up for the lack of staff.

Comment: Well you have the inside view - but simply even if SE had the money, you just can't automate dealing with people. That and it's been the promised solution for years. At this point I don't see any benefit that couldn't have been realized if it was really a solution

Comment: @JourneymanGeek The automation is for the part that isn't actually about people, so mostly vote fraud and routine support stuff. You can't automate the hard part, but vote fraud, vote invalidation and similar stuff should really be at least partially automated. I've no idea how much of a CMs time is taken by that kind of stuff, I'm only guessing here, but I don't think it's insignificant.

Comment: I don't even need an inside view for this; you can look at any number of organizations that've tried automating their way out of skilled labor, @Journeyman. The choice SE is facing isn't between hiring and equivalent automation; it's "some" automation or *nothing*: tasks just getting dropped because there's nothing & no one to do them. Both have already been happening for 3 years, as you well know - and you can probably guess at the relative proportions of each.

Comment: And well over the last 3 years and more, I am increasingly convinced that strategy might be harmful. It's downsizing stuff that has worked well for the community, on the promise of automation lowering workloads.

Answer (score 26):

Hi Teresa, thank you for posting this! We have wanted a clear picture of company structure for a long time, and this is a simple but clear explanation.

One question: do you have any oversight over the marketing/blog people? Because they can have an impact on our sites (for example, [choosing non-representative questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398166/2854284), [acting as if they determine site scopes](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/04/20/pandemic-changed-traffic-trends-stack-exchange-sites/#comment-754621)), and it can take a long time to get their attention ([three months for one of my requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343855/256282)).

Comment: I would say right now we have a partnership with the marketing team.  In not so recent past, it has mainly been reactive.  We are working to put process into place that includes reviewing content directed at the community, but its a challenge with the existing workload and number of team members to cover everything we want to.