# Flagging a moderator's comments

Tags: discussion, flags, moderators, community-managers

Being new to the site I have already witnessed a hell lot of work and responsibility a moderator has to undertake (at the least)... Just wanted to know what does happen when someone flags a moderator's comments?

Is the moderator himself/herself supposed to act on or is there a kind of judiciary link to check upon a moderator's actions?

NOTE: Here I imagine the judiciary being like a commune of SE moderators that check upon every other moderator's actions
.. Or does SE itself being a motherly body does so?

Answer (score 29):

When you flag a moderator's comment, the system treats it like any other flag and it will appear in the queue of all the moderators of that site.

That being said, moderation best practice is to avoid or at least be hyper aware of interacting with flags on your own posts. Usually we can get another mod (or, in extreme cases, a CM) to handle it. But there's nothing in the system that prevents us from doing it ourselves or any automatic oversight that is triggered by doing so that I am aware of. (SE certainly has the tools to investigate potential abuse of a moderator in this and other ways, but as far as I know, they must be told about the issue first in this case specifically).

A lot of SE moderation functions (and not just diamond moderating tasks) work on the basis on varying levels of trust that the person is doing what is in the best interest of the site, and this is another one of those cases.

Comment: @Rubikmoose Thanks moose.Btw what's a CM.I seem not to get a hang on it.

Comment: @bagagraacieu CM = Community Manager, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349266/334566

Comment: @PM2Ring thanks buddy