# Newsletter digest preview broken

Tags: bug, 500-server-error, community-digests

I clicked on "see an example newsletter" in this element on the sidebar of Stack Overflow:

[image: Screenshot of digest ad in sidebar]

It took me to https://stackoverflow.com/digest/preview, which displays the standard [500 error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLKWg.png). The [/digest/preview page on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/digest/preview) similarly displays a 500 error. I also received the same errors when opening the page in a private browsing session.

A quick browse of [the other digest previews](https://stackexchange.com/digests) suggests it's happening on all SE sites.

Comment: Are you or others still experiencing this issue? I just tried loading the SO digest preview link in your post, and it seemed to work; the same is true for a few others that I tried opening from your link to "the other digest previews".

Comment: @V2Blast I'm not now, no. They seem to be working

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard ?

Comment: Eh, I missed your last paragraph. Will delete the comment shortly.

Comment: @V2Blast working for me as well. Was something done, or was it just some temporary glitch that went away on its own?

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard My ? was just tagging you so you were looped in to V2Blast's comment. I wasn't meaning to be sassy about your previous comment haha. Repros are useful :)

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard: Not sure, I was just checking to see if I could reproduce it before I sent it to PubPlat, and I couldn't. So I suppose I'll just remove the [status-review] tag and close this as no longer reproducible for now...

Comment: @V2Blast fair, but you got me curious now! What is PubPlat? Googling it gave some shady results which I suppose aren't really related. ;-)

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard DuckDuckGo turned this up [https://stackoverflow.atlassian.net/browse/PUBPLAT-1975] ooooh :)

Comment: Oh, it's the team which handles building the public platform, guess that makes sense ;) "We have recently renamed the product development team that builds our public Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange sites to the Public Platform Team" [source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349266/the-community-teams-stack-exchange-and-how-we-work-together)

Comment: Huh, nice find! And yeah, this make sense.

Comment: @V2Blast on second thought, in such cases it would make more sense to tag the question as [tag:status-norepro] instead of closing. The "can't be reproduced" close reason is for cases where changes in the system caused the bug/request to become non-relevant, however there were no changes in this case. Can you please do it? Thanks! :)