# Please change "Blog" to indicate it’s a Stack Exchange blog, not a site blog

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, blog, wording, community-bulletin

Currently, each site has a listed "Blog":

> [image: Screenshot of Chinese.SE, highlighting the word "Blog"]

It just says "Blog" and it's prominent on each page.  I worry it could be mistaken for a site blog (e.g. at Chinese.SE, "plain text" could be related to Chinese natural language processing.)

However, it's a Stack-Exchange-wide blog, so its content is 90%+ StackOverflow and it [prominently lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343855/please-restrict-the-announcements-tag-of-the-blog-to-posts-which-are-actually-an) [off-topic posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301676/dont-show-tech-focused-blog-posts-on-non-tech-sites).  I'm hoping to indicate this with a minor change:

**Feature Request**: Please change "Blog" to indicate it’s a Stack Exchange blog, not a site blog.

A few possibilities:

- "Stack Overflow Blog"  (Similar to the post's "stackoverflow.blog".)
- "Stack Exchange Blog"
- "Network Blog"
- "Network Blog: *The Overflow*"
- "Blog: *The Overflow*"
- "*The Overflow* Blog"
- "*The Overflow*"

(Or any of the above with "Blog" replaced by "Bulletin".)

Or maybe even...

- "Stack Exchange Announcements"

...since it's [caused by the announcements tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343844/why-are-different-blog-articles-featured-on-different-sites/343846#343846).

Comment: @YaakovEllis:  It seems this is has been implemented: it says "The Overflow Blog".  Great, thanks!  Would you mind adding an answer and updating the tags? (Assuming someone else is not going to do so.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestions. The Community Bulletin section in the right sidebar has now been updated to label the company blog posts subsection as *The Overflow Blog*.

Comment: This is far worse than any of the suggested labels, and IMO even worse than when it just said "Blog". No one will know what "The Overflow" is, especially on non tech Stack **Exchange** sites, where users may not even know about Stack Overflow! I'd strongly recommend changing it to say the company blog, which is the most easily accessible label - everyone will understand what that refers to. Keep the name The Overflow to the blog itself.

Comment: @curiousdannii to be fair, it was second-last in the suggested labels.

Answer (score 21):

I'd go with "Company Blog" same as we see in the site switcher:

> [image: Site switcher with company blog title]

Answer (score 9):

Excellent suggestion.

Two, three years ago, when the blog slowly but steadily felt more and more like a rarely visited graveyard… few people cared enough I guess.

But now, SE Inc. themselves claim that they want to revive the blog, and they celebrate by adding fresh content there, which has a visible impact on visitor numbers.

And from that point of view: it's time to do some cleanup to get the house more tidy. Simple things can make a big difference, and this is a good example how a "too short" label can easily turn into a source of confusion.

People who know the blog, also know it primarily focuses on the "stackoverflow" side of the network, but people who start out in of the smaller communities might be surprised each time they click on links in that section.